# Actions before close python script

Tags: python

Hi i have an script in python that run in a infinite loop some actions, but sometimes i have to close the script and update it with a new version, make some works in the server, etc.

The question, is how can i do to stop the script and before close it, the script make some actions after the loop as close sqlite connection, close connection with a broker, etc.

what i do now is ctr+c until it stop (take few times before it finish) and then manually close sqlite connection, etc.

Comment: You could use a [context manager](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/) and tidy up in `__exit__`, or have an `except KeyboardInterrupt` or `finally` on a `try`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can catch a signal an execute something other then `sys.exit`

```
 import signal
 import sys

 def signal_handler(signal, frame):
     print 'You pressed Ctrl+C - or killed me with -2'
     #.... Put your logic here .....
     sys.exit(0)

 signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal_handler)
```

Comment: This works perfect to me. Any possibility to catch when the terminal is closed too?

Comment: You may need to eplore `SIGHUP` signal - this basically the signal that gets sent to the processes when the terminal disconnects.

Answer (score 4):

You could use the [atexit](https://docs.python.org/2/library/atexit.html) module:

```
import atexit

def cleanup():
    print "cleanup"
    # close connections, ...

atexit.register(cleanup)
```

The `cleanup()` function will be called on every normal termination (this includes Ctrl-C).

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `try-except` block around your loop and catch the `KeyboardInterrupt` exception. Or a `finally` block to also clean up if the program terminates in an orderly fashion. Your code should then look something like this:

```
try:
    <your loop goes here>
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    <handle error and do possible special cleanup>
finally:
    <do the cleanup that always has to happen>
```

Note that this way you only handle the case when you kill your script with a keyboard interrupt and no other case.

You could also used the `with` statement [see here for more info](http://effbot.org/zone/python-with-statement.htm) (as mentioned in the comments)

Answer (score 0):

```
import sys
try:
    # Program here
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    # Close connections
    sys.exit(0)
```

Comment: Please consider editing your post to add more explanation about what your code does and why it will solve the problem. An answer that mostly just contains code (even if it's working) usually wont help the OP to understand their problem.